# chrome://plugins/ not working

Tags: google-chrome

I used to manage plugins in Chrome by visiting `chrome://plugins/` but version 57 it says:

> The webpage at chrome://plugins/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Is there a way to manage plugins in the newest versions of Chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

chrome://plugins/ has been removed from Chrome version 57+. You can only manage plugins like Adobe Flash Player through chrome://settings/content/. Any other plugins are untouchable.

Comment: The relevant bug and rational can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615738).

Comment: [Deprecate chrome://plugins](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615738#c44) explains in detail the reasons the Chrome developers had to deprecate this feature.

Comment: What's interesting is that it seems to have kept my flash setting disabled from when it was available and now I cannot get back to it to change it.

Comment: In short it seems like chrome is moving away from plugins in favour of extensions.